# Change in PyQt QDialog Layout Does Not Update Correctly -- bug or my error?

Tags: python, layout, pyqt

I created a dialog to show two columns of radio buttons with the text for each button obtained from a network server. The button text in one column is static. The other changes. The dialog updates its display to show radio buttons as the dynamic list changes but the update is not correct. Old information remains visible.

My current design uses two QVBoxLayout (staticBox and dynamicBox) for the two columns. For each update, all radio buttons are removed from dynamicBox and deleted, then new radio buttons are added. I confirmed the VBox item count reduced to zero as items were removed and the button widgets are deleted but the update does not work properly. Although the old radio buttons are removed from the VBoxLayout, they continue to display on the dialog along with the new radio buttons.

I reduced my code to an example that replaces the network server with a simple routine that alternately returns one of two lists. I am using Python 3.8.10 with PyQt 5.14.1 (the underlying Qt version is 5.12.8).

The problem can be seen more easily by occasionally resizing the dialog. The dynamic radio buttons from previous iterations remain visible at whatever position they had when first displayed. They also continue to be working buttons whose selection is mutually exclusive.

I added a few print statements and noticed something curious. According to the print, more than one QWidgetItem has the same memory address. I checked for equality between items -- not true -- so is this a bug in how the print is rendered?

I would appreciate any suggestions you may have on how to get this working correctly.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class SelectDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, staticList, parent=None):
        super(SelectDialog, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.initWidgets(staticList)
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
        self.initUpdateTimer()

    def initUpdateTimer(self):
        self.toggle = 1
        self.updtTimer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.updtTimer.setInterval(3000)
        self.updtTimer.timeout.connect(self.updateDynamic)
        self.updtTimer.start()

    def updateDynamic(self):
        # update and show current list of dynamic items
        # save name of any current selection
        selection = None
        for rb in self.dynamicButtonList:
            if rb.isChecked():
                selection = rb.text()
        # clear button list
        self.dynamicButtonList.clear()
        if self.dynamicBox.count() > 1:
            print('\nQWidgetItems in layout box ----------------------------')
            for i in range(self.dynamicBox.count()):
                print('++++', self.dynamicBox.itemAt(i))
            print('\nCompare 0 : 1 ======> {}\n'.
                    format(self.dynamicBox.itemAt(0) == self.dynamicBox.itemAt(1)))
        # remove all items from the box layout
        while self.dynamicBox.count() > 0:
            item = self.dynamicBox.itemAt(0)
            w = item.widget()
            if w is not None:
                print('Removing item {:9}  {}'.format(w.text(), item))
                del w
            else:
                print('Removing item {:9}  {}'.format(' ', item))
            self.dynamicBox.removeItem(item)
            del item
        # get current list of dynamic items
        dynamicList = self.getDynamicList()
        # build widgets for all dynamic items
        if len(dynamicList) > 0:
            dynamicPrompt = QtWidgets.QLabel('Dynamic')
            self.dynamicBox.addWidget(dynamicPrompt)
            self.dynamicBox.addSpacing(10)
            for ex in (dynamicList):
                rb = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(ex, self)
                if selection == ex:
                    # restore previous selection
                    rb.setChecked(True)
                self.dynamicButtonList.append(rb)
                self.dynamicBox.addWidget(rb)
            self.dynamicBox.addStretch()
            self.divLine.setVisible(True)
        else:
            self.divLine.setVisible(False)
        # refresh dialog display
        self.update()
        self.app.processEvents()

    def getDynamicList(self):
        self.toggle = 1 - self.toggle
        if self.toggle == 0:
            return list()
        else:
            return ['Eight', 'Eleven']

    def initWidgets(self, staticList):
        mainBox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        #--- static and dynamic
        self.staticButtonList = list()
        self.dynamicButtonList = list()
        hBox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        # static
        staticBox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        staticPrompt = QtWidgets.QLabel('Static')
        staticBox.addWidget(staticPrompt)
        staticBox.addSpacing(10)
        for itm in staticList:
            rb = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(itm, self)
            self.staticButtonList.append(rb)
            staticBox.addWidget(rb)
        staticBox.addStretch()
        hBox.addStretch()
        hBox.addLayout(staticBox)
        # dynamic
        self.dynamicBox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        # insert divider between static and dynamic lists
        self.divLine = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.divLine.setFrameStyle(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.divLine.setVisible(False)
        hBox.addWidget(self.divLine)
        hBox.addLayout(self.dynamicBox)
        hBox.addStretch()
        #--- buttons
        btnBox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        cmdQuit = QtWidgets.QPushButton('&Quit')
        cmdQuit.clicked.connect(self.reject)
        btnBox.addStretch()
        btnBox.addWidget(cmdQuit)
        btnBox.addStretch()
        #--- complete the layout
        mainBox.addLayout(hBox)
        mainBox.addSpacing(15)
        mainBox.addLayout(btnBox)
        self.setLayout(mainBox)

    def reject(self):
        self.updtTimer.stop()
        super(SelectDialog, self).reject()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    staticList = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
    sd = SelectDialog(staticList)
    sd.exec_()
    print('\nFINI')
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: `del` does not remove an object, it removes its *reference*. Remove both `del` statements and replace `del w` with `w.deleteLater()`.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you. Your suggestion solved the problem.

Comment: You're welcome, but please don't edit a question to add the answer. The comment above is sufficient along with what provided in the related post.